# What's the best way to create a Rails validation based on an geographic zone or an address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, activerecord, geolocation, maps

I have no idea what strategy to take with this, but I'd like to create a user signup form in Rails that only allows you to sign up if you're in a certain geographic area. For instance 32205, East of Cassat or 32206, South of 8th.

Does anyone know a good approach to take with something like this?

A yaml file with all of the known, valid addresses? Is there something you can do with the google maps api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geocoder gem could help you with this... If you geocode the user's entered address, you could then have another validation like so:

```
validates :is_in_valid_area?

def is_in_valid_area?
  return unless geocoded?
  distance_from([40.714,-100.234]) < 30
end
```

You'll probably need to define the geocoded? method yourself to check if coordinates exist.

http://www.rubygeocoder.com
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder